# Is the commutant of a semisimple algebra also semisimple?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

Let $A\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be an algebra of matrices over $\mathbb{F}$, and suppose it is semi-simple. Is $Z=\{g\in M_n(\mathbb{F})\,|\,gX=Xg\,\forall X\in A\}$ also semisimple?

Comment: What set does $g$ range over? $A$? All matrices?

Comment: Yes, sorry, explained poorly.

Comment: You didn't answer my question though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's 2 in the  morning here. Over all square matrices of fixed size and entries in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @EmilSinclair hi, posts that are just problem statements are generally discouraged. What do you have to contribute in terms of work and context?